# Ubuntu won’t install on an old white plastic MacBbook

Tags: system-installation, live-usb, etcher

After preparing the USB flash drive for Ubuntu installation using Etcher and holding down the Option key and pressing the power button, I only get the hard drive icon and no other options. Is my MacBook too old?

Comment: You've provided no clear details for us to help, we don't know what architecture your *old macbook* is (*there have been two different & incompatible architectures made over the years of production*), nor given details of what Ubuntu product, release or that it's the same architecture as your *unstated* macbook.

Comment: the color and composition of your macbook is irrelevant; what is relevant is the model/architecture/year of manufacture of your macbook. Also details on where you got an iso from, and what process you used to try to install it

Comment: Hi and thanks for your reeponse. It is a 2.0  ghz core 2 Duo (T7200), 13 inch, model a1181, 2 cores, 64 bit architecture, at least 1gb ram.

Comment: Downloaded Ubuntu for desktop 22.04.2. And flashed onto usb stick using balenaetcher.

Comment: 64 bit architecture is *vague*, there is ARM64 which is the current architecture used by Apple, PPC64EL or the 64bit version of older IBM PPC (PowerPC) processors that Apple used (apple hardware was only 32bit though when using PPC) and of course AMD64 or the AMD created 64-bit version of x86 (16-32bit) created by intel. There are many 64-bit architectures (ARM, PPC, AMD with 64-bit being the wordsize & not architecture).  c2d is/was AMD64 though.  Please add your hardware details & Ubuntu 22.04.2 Desktop OS detail to your question (this is a Question & Answer site, not a forum).

Comment: Hi, the processor has merom intel64 architecture. The Ubuntu file name downloaded is as follows: ubuntu-22.04.2-desktop-amd64.

Comment: Hi guiverc, can you help? Do you need more details? Kind regards